# Как найти вещественную и мнимую часть?

Tags: математика, matlab, mathematica

[image]

Подскажите смогу ли я это посчитать через Matlab или Mathcad, если да то как.
Или может как в ручную ,то с чего начать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через MATLAB можно так (если установлен Symbolic math toolbox):

```
syms w % Объявляем w как символьный объект
assume(w,'real') % w - вещественное число
W= 2.71*(0.055*(1j*w)^3+0.46*(1j*w)^2+1.2*1j*w)/(0.061*(1j*w)^4+... % ну и так далее
real(W) % вещественая часть
imag(W) % мнимая часть
```